# ng-polymer-elements Support for multiple data bindings

Tags: polymer

I have a created a simple age-slider web component which accepts name and age. Something like below.

`<age-slider name="{{name}}" age="{{age}}"/>`

So wanted to use this with Angular. With ng-polymer-elements i could only bind one variable as below code

`<age-slider ng-model="name" age="{{age}}"/>`

Is it possible to bind two variables with ng-polymer-elements?